# Stuck on finding the Inverted z transformation

Tags: z-transform

I have the following equation :

$X(z) = \frac{1-z^{-1}}{1-0.25z^{-1}}$

The question I must answer is pretty simple : I need to find the inverted z transform and then create a graph for that.

The only additional information I have is that I "inspire" myself (actual translated words) from the z transform equation $X(z) = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty x[n]z^{-n}$

I do not know how to start from there and any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the inverse $z$-transform by using linearity. Note that (writing $a = 0.25$), we have $$X(z) = \frac{1}{1- az^{-1}} - \frac{z^{-1}}{1 - az^{-1}}.$$ So if $x_{1}[n]$ is the inverse $z$-transform of $\frac{1}{1- az^{-1}}$ and $x_{2}[n]$ is that of $\frac{z^{-1}}{1- az^{-1}}$, then your answer is $x[n] = x_{1}[n] - x_{2}[n]$. You should either know or be able to look up the inverse $z$-transform of $\frac{1}{1- az^{-1}} $ (it can be found in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Table_of_common_Z-transform_pairs)). To get the inverse $z$-transform of $\frac{z^{-1}}{1- az^{-1}} $, use the "time delay" property displayed in the table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't think about splitting my equation to manageable known transforms. Thank you very much.